# Connecting to database using apache pivot?

Tags: apache-pivot

I am new to desktop applications.can someone explain on how to connect to database using apache pivot?
if it is not possible please list any other options to achieve it

I want to insert some records into a table in database (like MS Access,MYSQL,etc.....).
If anyone has worked on such a requirement using apache pivot, please help me out with some sample code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't really have anything specifically to do with Pivot. You should learn the fundamentals of the Java database API (JDBC) by reading the following [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/).

Answer (score 0):

As Benjamin Gale posted, Pivot is a GUI framework that really doesn't need or have any APIs to deal with connecting to databases.  But, JDBC can be used in a Pivot application to do that, just like any other Java application.